# Voting Option Forward response to email Interop

Tags: c#, email, outlook, interop

I am trying to use c# Microsoft Outlook Interop to send an email with voting options. The only issue is that I want to not receive the response but rather the responses be sent to another email address (not mine). 
[image]

Currently my code sends the voting responses to myself which is not what i want. I want to send it to a given email that I provide in string format.

This is my existing code:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        mail.Body= "hi";
        mail.VotingOptions = "Cheese;Combo;Maybe;";


        mail.Recipients.Add("abc@gmail.com");
        mail.Send();
```

Comment: have you tried sending the reply to properties?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The only properties I see are ReplyRecipientsName and ReplyRecipients. Wouldn't this resolve in an empty array since I currently won't have any recipients as it is a sent mail not a received mail.

Comment: try it. i think thats the collections that drives that box you have highlighted.

Comment: Just tried it. Guess I should've tried that before instead of just thinking of it as something else. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MailItem.ReplyRecipients.Add`.

Comment: Daniel helped me out but you were the first to write the answer. Kudos.